# How to hide the menubar in non-native applications?

Tags: applications, gtk

I just came from Ubuntu, where all (or almost all) applications use the global menu to show the menubar of each application. However, here in elementary OS I'm having problems with all non-elementary applications.

Here are a couple of examples:

**Atom text editor**

[image]

**Sublime text editor**

[image]

As you can see, the menubar is displayed as a grayish bar wasting pixels in all those applications. My question is: Is there a way to hide the menu bar? Some applications (like Firefox) toggle the menu bar using the <kbd>alt</kbd> key. However, this does not work in every case.

Comment: Are you not able to go to `View > Toggle Menu Bar` in Atom? In Sublime it's `View > Hide Menu`.

Comment: OMG! I love you! hahaha so simple, thanks! <3

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to hide the menubar of *all* apps or just these two? You can see the menubar here because elementary is not Ubuntu and they behave differently. If you are only interested in these two apps, then you should re-write your question to make that clear.

Comment: Of course a fix for all the non-elementary applications would be better but this will do for now. I know it is different from ubuntu, hence I don't know the OS and that is the reason I'm asking the community to help me a little, so far I haven't found anything useful for what I'm looking for. And my question is to find a better menu-applications integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no universal way to hide all menu bars.

To toggle the menu in Atom: `View > Toggle Menu Bar`

To toggle the menu in Sublime Text: `View > Hide Menu`

Comment: Doesn't really look like a solution. As far as I understand OP wants this for all applications, not just for sublime/atom. Approach of hiding panel for each application is an overkill even if all applications allowed this (but as we know - that's a rare functionality).

Comment: Not a final solution but close enough. I'm guessing that hiding the menus more native-ish way needs coding a little bit more the elemenary's core.

Answer (score 1):

## For most applications:

This is not a feature of elementary.

Though *technically*, you could enable the appmenu indicator (I've tried this before), it leads to a misaligned clock, which of course would not be a welcome result.

---

## For those that support it:

Some applications allow you to hide the menu in their preferences. In such cases, you can simply disable or hide the menu in this manner.

---

## For application that do not support it:

You can report a bug to the application developer requesting this feature (hiding the menu). However, do not *expect* this to change, as many applications have good reason for having a visible menu bar.

**For example:** GIMP and Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

This feature does not exist in "stock" elementary OS, however, you can search on Launchpad for projects that introduce this functionality (this functionality you desire is called global menu) and install it via ppa.

I know at least two projects:

1. wingpanel-featured
2. super-wingpanel

Also you might want to submit a blueprint to wingpanel's launchpad to introduce this optional functionality :)

Comment: This has been brought up before, and as far as I know, the developers have no plans of adding this feature.